# Alternative to using Hangfire in Azure App Server for computational expensive operations

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have an Asp.Net Core website running on Azure as an App Service. The website is tasked with listing various calculations, providing input screens for entering in calculation values and then reports for viewing the calculation outputs and inputs that were used. This data is persisted within an Azure SQL Database whilst the solution itself includes a class library project that actually performs the calculations. These calculations expect a series of input parameters and return a series of output values that are then stored in the database.
Most of the calculations can be very computationally expensive and could take quite a while to run (worse case - up to an hour). At the moment we have incorporated HangFire so that the actual calculation function can be queued up and run on a background thread.

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => _calculationRunService.RunCalculation(runID));
```

This works but is not very performant and scalable as the user-base increases and calculations become more complex. I am therefore looking for some advice on whether one of the other Azure services may be suitable for replacing the Hangfire part?

Comment: Try to look into Azure Functions. It uses serverless approach and perfect for this kind of tasks

Answer (score 3):

You said the computation takes close to an hour.  What do you think is the contention point

- CPU ? Do you need more cores
- IO ? Do you need caching (or) high end hardware
- Memory ?  Do you see a lot of paging when the computation runs  ?

If you run your computation locally, you will pretty much know the bottleneck and the area to scale. Then there are several options in azure based on the bottleneck both in hardware and in managed services.

For CPU intensive work

- [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs) should be preferred. It's a special kind  of app service, and can be configured.
- [Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/) if another  alternative for cpu intensive jobs

The  above two are managed services. Alternatively you can define your own VM's with superier hardware and ACU's for any customization beyond this.